# "Input string was not in a correct format." Exception in WPF Datagrid

Tags: wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I have a BindingListCollectionView connected to the DataContext of a datagrid. The datagrid now shows the list of items of the BindingListCollectionView.
But when I click on the last row to add a new item. I get an "Input string was not in a correct format." exception.

When I step with the debugger through the WpfToolkit library the exception happens in the private void MakeFullRowSelection(object dataItem, bool allowsExtendSelect, bool allowsMinimalSelect) function of the file DataGrid.cs at the line EndUpdateSelectedItems().

Can someone suggest how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually to do with the SelectedItem. If you remove the SelcetedItem binding it should work, or if you run in debug mode. (Known bug see link below)
[link text](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/474144/binding-to-datagrid-selecteditem-causes-app-to-crash-with-debugger-attached)